# Finding ObjectId's Mongoose with and's and or's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are implementing searching in our application. We must display all items that are public OR all private items that are followed by the user. The schema is below.

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    .
    .
    .
    followers: {
        type: Array
    }
}
```

Followers are filled with user's objectIDs.
And I'm trying to find it like with this:

```
Item.find()
   .and([
    { name: new RegExp(searchText, 'i') },
    {
      $or: [
        { private: false },
        {
          $and: [
            { private: true },
            { followers: user._id }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
  .exec(function(err, item) {
    if(err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
    done(null, user, Item);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Query#or](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or) helper along with [$and](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

```
Item.find()
    .or([ 
          { "private": true  },
          { $and: [{ private: true },{ followers: user._id }
          ]} 
     ])
     .exec(function(err, item) {
        ...
      }
```